# Send an HTTP response with trailers using the Java HTTP Server

Tags: java, http-headers, chunked, rfc2616, com.sun.net.httpserver

Using the default implementation of the HTTP server shipped with the JDK (the `com.sun.net.httpserver` package), how do I send any [trailers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer) after I've written out the HTTP response body?

```http
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Trailer: Expires

7\r\n
Mozilla\r\n
9\r\n
Developer\r\n
7\r\n
Network\r\n
0\r\n
Expires: Wed, 21 Oct 2015 07:28:00 GMT\r\n
\r\n
```

It's quite possible to enable the chunked `Transfer-Encoding` by calling [`HttpExchange.sendResponseHeaders()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#sendResponseHeaders-int-long-) with a zero `responseLength`.

Yet, I'm looking at the source code of `sun.net.httpserver.ChunkedOutputStream` as well as its usages, but it seems that support for trailers is not implemented.